# How to use Yelp v3 Search API sample in php

Tags: php, html, api, search, yelp

I am currently using the Yelp API v3 and am testing some of their sample code. I have never used php before so it is quite confusing, but I am just wondering, where would I set the term and location equal to the users input in this script? Say I have an input for term and location in html, where in this script do I do $term = inputTerm and $location = inputLocation?

```
`#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
/**
* Yelp Fusion API code sample.
*
* This program demonstrates the capability of the Yelp Fusion API
* by using the Business Search API to query for businesses by a 
* search term and location, and the Business API to query additional 
* information about the top result from the search query.
* 
* Please refer to http://www.yelp.com/developers/v3/documentation 
* for the API documentation.
* 
* Sample usage of the program:
* `php sample.php --term="dinner" --location="San Francisco, CA"`
*/
// OAuth credential placeholders that must be filled in by users.
// You can find them on
// https://www.yelp.com/developers/v3/manage_app
$CLIENT_ID = "abcd";
$CLIENT_SECRET =    "abcd";
// Complain if credentials haven't been filled out.
assert($CLIENT_ID, "Please supply your client_id.");
assert($CLIENT_SECRET, "Please supply your client_secret.");
// API constants, you shouldn't have to change these.
$API_HOST = "https://api.yelp.com";
$SEARCH_PATH = "/v3/businesses/search";
$BUSINESS_PATH = "/v3/businesses/";  // Business ID will come after slash.
$TOKEN_PATH = "/oauth2/token";
$GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";
// Defaults for our simple example.
$DEFAULT_TERM = "dinner";
$DEFAULT_LOCATION = "San Francisco, CA";
$SEARCH_LIMIT = 10;

function getQuery(){
echo $_GET['latlon'];
//echo $_GET['q'];
$query = $_GET['q'];
//break the query up into parts 
$first_space= strpos($query, " ");
$term = substr($query, 0, $first_space);
echo $term;

}
/**
* Given a bearer token, send a GET request to the API.
* 
* @return   OAuth bearer token, obtained using client_id and client_secret.
*/
function obtain_bearer_token() {
try {
    # Using the built-in cURL library for easiest installation.
    # Extension library HttpRequest would also work here.
    $curl = curl_init();
    if (FALSE === $curl)
        throw new Exception('Failed to initialize');
    $postfields = "client_id=" . $GLOBALS['CLIENT_ID'] .
        "&client_secret=" . $GLOBALS['CLIENT_SECRET'] .
        "&grant_type=" . $GLOBALS['GRANT_TYPE'];
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $GLOBALS['API_HOST'] . $GLOBALS['TOKEN_PATH'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  // Capture response.
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",  // Accept gzip/deflate/whatever.
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (FALSE === $response)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if (200 != $http_status)
        throw new Exception($response, $http_status);
    curl_close($curl);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
}
$body = json_decode($response);
$bearer_token = $body->access_token;
return $bearer_token;
}
/** 
* Makes a request to the Yelp API and returns the response
* 
* @param    $bearer_token   API bearer token from obtain_bearer_token
* @param    $host    The domain host of the API 
* @param    $path    The path of the API after the domain.
* @param    $url_params    Array of query-string parameters.
* @return   The JSON response from the request      
*/
function request($bearer_token, $host, $path, $url_params = array()) {
// Send Yelp API Call
try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    if (FALSE === $curl)
        throw new Exception('Failed to initialize');
    $url = $host . $path . "?" . http_build_query($url_params);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  // Capture response.
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",  // Accept gzip/deflate/whatever.
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer " . $bearer_token,
            "cache-control: no-cache",
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (FALSE === $response)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if (200 != $http_status)
        throw new Exception($response, $http_status);
    curl_close($curl);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
}
return $response;
}
/**
* Query the Search API by a search term and location 
* 
* @param    $bearer_token   API bearer token from obtain_bearer_token
* @param    $term        The search term passed to the API 
* @param    $location    The search location passed to the API 
* @return   The JSON response from the request 
*/
function search($bearer_token, $term, $location) {
$url_params = array();

$url_params['term'] = $term;
$url_params['location'] = $location;
$url_params['limit'] = $GLOBALS['SEARCH_LIMIT'];

return request($bearer_token, $GLOBALS['API_HOST'], $GLOBALS['SEARCH_PATH'],   $url_params);
}
/**
* Query the Business API by business_id
* 
* @param    $bearer_token   API bearer token from obtain_bearer_token
* @param    $business_id    The ID of the business to query
* @return   The JSON response from the request 
*/
function get_business($bearer_token, $business_id) {
$business_path = $GLOBALS['BUSINESS_PATH'] . urlencode($business_id);

return request($bearer_token, $GLOBALS['API_HOST'], $business_path);
}
/**
* Queries the API by the input values from the user 
* 
* @param    $term        The search term to query
* @param    $location    The location of the business to query
*/
function query_api($term, $location) {     
$bearer_token = obtain_bearer_token();
$response = json_decode(search($bearer_token, $term, $location));
$business_id = $response->businesses[0]->id;

print sprintf(
    "%d businesses found, querying business info for the top result    \"%s\"\n\n",         
    count($response->businesses),
    $business_id
);

$response = get_business($bearer_token, $business_id);

print sprintf("Result for business \"%s\" found:\n", $business_id);
$pretty_response = json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT |  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
print "$pretty_response\n";
}
/**
* User input is handled here 
*/
$longopts  = array(
"term::",
"location::",
);

$options = getopt("", $longopts);
$term = $options['term'] ?: $GLOBALS['DEFAULT_TERM'];
$location = $options['location'] ?: $GLOBALS['DEFAULT_LOCATION'];
//getQuery();
query_api($term, $location);
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do that for you. The example doesn't take input filtering into consideration, so you'll want to mysql_real_escape the inputs first.

```
// Defaults for our simple example.
$DEFAULT_TERM           = "Dinner";
$DEFAULT_LOCATION       = "White House, TN";
$SEARCH_LIMIT           = 0;
$REVIEWS                = 0;

if(isset($_GET['term'])) $DEFAULT_TERM = $_GET['term'];
if(isset($_GET['loc']) && $_GET['loc'] !='') $DEFAULT_LOCATION = $_GET['loc'] ;
if(isset($_GET['limit'])) $SEARCH_LIMIT = $_GET['limit'];
if(isset($_GET['reviews'])) $REVIEWS = $_GET['reviews'];
```

And your form would look like this

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="search"/>
    <input type="text" name="loc" placeholder="zipcode"/>
    Results <select name="limit">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    Show reviews <input type="checkbox" name="reviews" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```